# Java: opening a resource (txt file) which is in a jar with OS standard application

Tags: java, resources, jar, text-files

i get the error "AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical".
-I'm trying to use the java.awt.Desktop api to open a text file with the OS's default application.
-The application i'm running is launched from the autorunning jar.
I understand that getting a "file from a file" is not the correct way and that it's called resource. I still can't open it and can't figure out how to do this.

`open(new File((this.getClass().getResource("prova.txt")).toURI()));`

Is there a way to open the resource with the standard os application from my application?
Thx :)

Comment: Is `prova.txt` in your classpath? `getResource()` will only work for files in your classpath.

Comment: yes it is, and it works when i open it within eclipse, when in a jar it's impossible :)

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to extract the file from the Jar to the temp folder and open that temporary file, much like you would do with files in a Zip-file (which a Jar basically is).

Comment: ok, that's a solution that i'm trying to avoid, i'm creating an installer and i'd like not to extract anything until the user clicks "install".
Is there a way to do it "on the fly"? :) thx :)

Comment: @Alessandro I don't think so, since you can't rely on standard OS applications to be able to read from sources other than plain files.

Comment: @Allessando, please put yourself into the viewpoint of your OS or the Application you want to start!! How the heck should Word e.g. be able to open "C:\...\autorunning.jar:\your.package.file.doc"? Obviously Word and any other Program can not look inside of your Jar file, so you need to extract your "File.doc" into some tmp folder and start Word e.g. then.

Comment: yeah.. i'm figuring that out.. i though java could create a "ghost" or a virtual document to make it openable :D
thx everybody!

Comment: @Alessandro The "ghost" document is actually your temporary file :)

Comment: yeah, i'm gonna do that way ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to extract file to /tmp folder. You can read it directly using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()'. But note that path depend on where your txt file is and what's your class' package. If your txt file is packaged in root of jar use '"/prova.txt"'. (pay attention on leading slash).

Comment: This does not "open the file with the standard application" but opens it inside the JVM for reading with a Java program ... that means the running program is now reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can open it with external applications. As far as i know, all installers extract their compressed content to a temp location and delete them afterwards.

But you can do it inside your Java code with Class.getResource(String name)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: I tried, it works in eclipse but no results from inside the jar :(

Comment: In order for this to work, the file you want to access has to be in your classpath. In eclipse, put it in src or subfolder of src, and eclipse will copy it to bin when building. With default settings, when you export something as a runnable jar, eclipse doesn't include folders outside the classpath. You can rename the jar file to .zip and check it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

#### Wrong

```
open(new File((this.getClass().getResource("prova.txt")).toURI()));
```

#### Right

[image: EULA]

```
/**

Do you accept the License Agreement of XYZ app.?

*/
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class ShowThyself {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get an URL to a document..
        File file = new File("ShowThyself.java");
        final URL url = file.toURI().toURL();

        // ..then do this
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JEditorPane license = new JEditorPane();
                try {
                    license.setPage(url);
                    JScrollPane licenseScroll = new JScrollPane(license);
                    licenseScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(305,90));

                    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        null,
                        licenseScroll,
                        "EULA",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        System.out.println("Install!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Maybe later..");
                    }
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        "Could not read license!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [JarFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) and [JarEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarEntry.html) classes from JDK. This allows to load a file from JarFile.

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("jar_file_Name");
JarEntry entry = jarFile.getJarEntry("resource_file_Name_inside_jar");
InputStream stream = jarFile.getInputStream(entry); // this input stream can be used for specific need
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're passing to can accept a `java.net.URL`this will work:

`this.getClass().getResource("prova.txt")).toURI().toURL()`